# Infinite loop React Native Screen due to fetch and useState

Tags: react-native

I'm having an infinite loop due to the change of state on react native, the problem is that I tried to fix it with Use Effect Hook and was impossible.

That is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Leaderboard from 'react-native-leaderboard';
import { useEffect } from 'react/cjs/react.production.min';

const LeaderBoardScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const baseUrl = Constants.manifest.extra.backend_url;
    const [token, setToken] = React.useState(null);
    const [users, setUsers] = React.useState(null);

    _retrieveToken = async () => {
        try {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
            setToken(token);
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert("SESIÓN FINALIZADA");
        }
    };

    _retrieveToken();

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
    };

    fetch(`${baseUrl}/user/top`, requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data == undefined) {
                Alert.alert(
                    "Usuario inválido",
                    "el usuario no existe, o la contraseña o usuario son incorrectas ¿Estás seguro de que tienes cuenta?"
                );
            }
            console.log(data);
            setUsers(data);
        });

    return (
        <Leaderboard
            data={users}
            sortBy='highScore'
            labelBy='userName'
            icon='icon' />
    );
}

export default LeaderBoardScreen;
```

It starts sending GET to my back end in a infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Try importing useEffect from React perhaps instead of where you have imported it from.

Answer (score 1):

That's because fetch and get token are being called on every render, you should move the function call inside a useEffect, (Or React Query useQuery if you want a 3rd party library)

The following code gets the token after the first render and then runs the fetches whenever the token changes

```
const requestOptions = (token) => ({
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
    });

const LeaderBoardScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const baseUrl = Constants.manifest.extra.backend_url;
    const [token, setToken] = React.useState(null);
    const [users, setUsers] = React.useState(null);

    _retrieveToken = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
            setToken(token)
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert("SESIÓN FINALIZADA");
        }
    },[])

useEffect(()=>{
_retrieveToken()
},[_retrieveToken])



useEffect(()=>{
    if(!!token){
    fetch(`${baseUrl}/user/top`, requestOptions(token))
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data == undefined) {
                Alert.alert(
                    "Usuario inválido",
                    "el usuario no existe, o la contraseña o usuario son incorrectas ¿Estás seguro de que tienes cuenta?"
                );
            }
            console.log(data);
            setUsers(data);
        })
    }
},[token])

    return (
        <Leaderboard
            data={users}
            sortBy='highScore'
            labelBy='userName'
            icon='icon' />
    );
}

export default LeaderBoardScreen;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. But I am getting a error that I dont understand: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: I fixed it, i imported badly the useEffect, thanks a lot friend, its working now